# How to generate file link without expiry?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, boto

In AWS S3 how to generate file download url for a file without expiry.

```
conn = boto.connect_s3(awsAccessKey, awsSecret)

# Get bucket instance.
bucket = conn.get_bucket(bktName)

fileKey = bucket.get_key(fileKey)
url = fileKey.generate_url(expires_in=None, query_auth=True, force_http=True)
print url
```

How to generate url for file without expiry ?

Answer (score 5):

According to the latest docs (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html):

> A presigned URL can be valid for a maximum of seven days because the
>   signing key you use in signature calculation is valid for up to seven
>   days.

Since the signature itself can only be valid for seven days, there's no way for a signed URL to be valid for more than seven days. The only way to have a permanently valid URL is to make the file public.

Answer (score -1):

The link expiration is to allow limited access to private files without exposing the authentication keys.

If you want to make a file always available, either make the file public, or provide permissions to other s3 users.